# Как правильно: Из Иркутска или с Иркутска?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно написать: вас беспокоит коллега из Иркутска или коллега с Иркутска?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: вас беспокоит коллега из Иркутска. Для города используется только предлог ИЗ, предлог С характерен для территории, например:

"Рядом профессор-филолог Трушнов, откуда-то с Поволжья, у окна ― Арутюнян, бывший инженер-строитель из Ленинграда" (Е. С. Гинзбург).

Это тема пространственных предлогов: из предмета/ с поверхности предмета.

Comment: Выходит, я еду на Поволжье?

Comment: Не выходит, потому что обычно едут в конкретное место, а не на всё Поволжье, а вот отдыхают или работают На Поволжье (не указывается определенное место), например: "Работал на Поволжье репортером".

Comment: Вот уж не встречал никогда. Последняя фраза – это цитата?

Comment: Цитата, конечно. "Работал на Поволжье репортером, равнялся на старших братьев, большевиков; арестовывался, своим политическим рождением обязан Февральской революции. (Александр Иличевский). "В сырье окружающей его жизни, среди мелких скопидомских нажив... он себя чувствовал на Поволжье, как в девственном лесу, еще не тронутом человеческой энергией (К.С. Петров-Водкин. Моя повесть).

Comment: Ну, даже если и цитата... Все равно ведь неправильно. В "в -- из" и "на -- с" исключений нет. В Закавказье -- из Закавказья, в Приуралье -- из Приуралья, в Поволжье -- из Поволжья (но на Волге -- с Волги, естественно) и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Из Иркутска. Об этих предлогах можете прочитать здесь: [Грамма.ру](http://l.ask.fm/goto/50aiCb_tfbeICH49l3Xu8ohzvw_NwNG7_0Hjoa_qlGyaClIuJ7kdcRDgvnoAQ2gzWVaKfbUs-T0,)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

В этом контексте возможно только "из Иркутска".

Ситуации с предлогом "с" принципиально возможны, но их крайне мало. Один рейс из Москвы сняли с Иркутска (= с направления на Иркутск) и перенаправили на Магадан. Чисто абстрактно можно "с Иркутска" снять какую-нибудь задолженность или статус.